# No serializer found for class common.api.soap.wsdl.Address error in javscript remoting

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have a javascript remoting call returning all fields for a set of contact IDs. When one of the contacts has a populated mailing address I get the following error:

> No serializer found for class common.api.soap.wsdl.Address

I'm assuming this is an issue because I'm getting every field for the contact using this to build my dynamic SOQL query:

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

**Update** I'm able to avoid the error by explicitly excluding 'mailingaddress' when the query is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hit something similar when I was pulling all columns for Contact and then trying to re-insert the object in another sandbox:

> Unable to create instance of the deserializer shared.xml.soap.serialization.BeanDeserializer for type: class common.api.soap.wsdl.Address and element: null

When you fetch all columns for Contact, the address fields are returned separately (MailingStreet, MailingCity etc) and (since API 30.0) also as a [compound field](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_address.htm) 'MailingAddress' which is a whole XML structure of its own. That is, its not just a compound string, its a whole load of seperate fields in their own 'object'.

Looks like support for serializing or deserializing these compound fields is lacking in some places in the API - I was getting the error when trying a create() call against the partner API.

As you say, the solution is to avoid fetching the compound field in the first place and just use the old separate fields.

The describeSObject metadata can be used to avoid these fields - if fieldType = address then its one of these compound fields and should (maybe) be avoided.

C# example:

```
List<string> fieldNames = meta.fields.Where(f.type != fieldType.address).Select(f => f.name).ToList<string>();
```

... gives all field names for the object except the compound address fields (where 'meta' is of type DescribeSObjectResult as returned by the API)

Comment: yep, this is pretty much the same conclusion and workaround I came to. Not ideal but this compound Address field seems to be the only example I've run into so far.